# html required not working with onclick

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following which I use for submitting forms on my site:

```
<a onclick="document.forms['REGform'].submit(); return false;" class="button" href="javascript:;">Register</a>
```

I have inputs within the form with the required tag but this does not seem to fire them? Meaning doesn't stop empty inputs being submitted.

If I use a normal submit button it works fine by the way - is onclick not a recognised way to submit a form within html5?

Comment: Why do you want to use javascript?

Comment: yes, why not an input-submit? and tag-validators don't work in every browser to

Comment: I am using js as I use a sprite for the button as a background on a class so I can change the button text

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is the `submit()` method, not the use of `onclick` (although you can't avoid the former if you want to submit using JS instead of HTML).

Submitting using JS causes the form's validation steps to be skipped (although you can re-implement them in JS (with [`checkValidity()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-form-checkvalidity)).

> The submit() method, when invoked, must submit the form element from the form element itself, with the scripted-submit flag set.

— http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-form-submit

> If the scripted-submit flag is not set, and the submitter element's no-validate state is false, then interactively validate the constraints of form and examine the result: if the result is negative (the constraint validation concluded that there were invalid fields and probably informed the user of this) then abort these steps.

— http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#form-submission-algorithm

Answer (score 6):

Here is how you can do

```
<a onclick="CheckValidation();" class="button" href="javascript:;">Register</a>

function CheckValidation()
{

    var isValidForm = document.forms['REGform'].checkValidity();
    if (isValidForm)
    {
        document.forms['REGform'].submit();
    }
    else
    {

        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: doesn't for me i'm afraid, does nothing at all - and I corrected the case of CheckValidation

Answer (score -4):

```
<a class="button" href="javascript:document.forms['REGform'].submit(); return false;">Register</a>
```

or

```
<a onclick="document.forms['REGform'].submit(); return false;" class="button">Register</a>
```

Comment: This is just a splurge of code. At best it is a "spot the difference solution", but I can't see anything that might make a difference. Please explain why this should make a difference.

Comment: What is working? The original code in the question? If so, say so in a comment. The code you've changed? If so, explain what you've changed and why it makes it work.

Comment: — What first post? Do you mean the question? I have. I still have no idea what your answer is trying to say.