# How do I make a field required in HTML?

Tags: html, forms, validation

I can't figure out why the new `required` attribute of HTML seems to not be working, and I know my simple code seems to be okay. What should I do to make this work?

Here is my code in HTML:

```
<input type = "text" class = "txtPost" placeholder = "Post a question?" required>
<button class = "btnPost btnBlue">Post</button>
```

Correct me if I'm wrong but, if ever I run the code in the browser and click the button without any value in the textbox it should have a tooltip showing that that field was required, shouldn't it? But nothing happens no matter how many times you click the button. Am I misunderstood on how to use the *required* attribute?

I am running my code in Google Chrome 28. This is with `<!doctype HTML>`.

Comment: And do you have a form around your input field and button?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Try putting it inside a form tag and closing the input tag:

```
<form>
  <input type = "text" class = "txtPost" placeholder = "Post a question?" required />
  <button class = "btnPost btnBlue">Post</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thankz for your input man, this solves my problem. I usually not making any `form` tags in my inputs because I am getting their values with their corresponding `id`'s or `class` names but now I know how important the `form` tag was.

Answer (score 60):

Make sure that novalidate attribute is not set to your form tag

Comment: Interesting; I typically use the Rails framework when building web apps and never have I found the `novalidate ` attribute appended to my form until today; I didn't even know to look for this until reading your comment :thumbs_up:

Answer (score 16):

Absence of Submit field element in the form also causes this error.
In the case of  "button" field  handled by JS to submit form  lacks the necessity of Submit button hence Required doesn't Work

Answer (score 6):

As long as have added **type="submit"** to button you are good.

```
 <form action="">
    <input type="text" placeholder="name" required>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually speaking, when I tried this, it worked only when I set the action and method value for the form. Funny how it works though!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I was doing a onClick on the submit button and that was causing the problem. Instead, try to put a onSubmit="anyAction" in the form and that should work.

Answer (score 1):

*here a summary for what I found:*
**1-** you have to be sure that the button is type of "submit" not a type of "button", actually the button will be type of "submit" by default so you dont have to clarify the type any more.

```html
 <form id="myform">
          <input type = "text" required />
          <button id="mybutton">Post</button>
        </form>
```

**2-** you must submit the form using the button not other way, my problem was submitting my form using JavaScript with form attribute while the type of my button is "button"
so I did this and worked;
here was my problem

```
document.getElementById("myform").submit();
```

and this is the correction:

```
 document.getElementById("mybutton").type = "submit";
  document.getElementById("mybutton").submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Seven years late, but I have a similar issue, and I realised it was caused by the refreshing of the page by the form submiting. As I set it to not auto refresh on submit, I had enough time to see the browser actualy require for the input to get filled.

Answer (score 0):

In React, after wrapping your inputs with a form, you can use the `onSubmit={}` attribute instead of `onClick={}`. In this particular problem (pertaining to the question), others might want to see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9066771/14382403).

**Important to note:** (for React) If you want to utilize the `e.preventDefault()` method, add the `onSubmit={(e) => e.preventDefault()}` attribute to your form tag directly, and use the `onClick={}` in your submit input or button.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me when I had an onclick on my button that passed my validate function. Instead i passed the function to onsubmit in the form tag.
Before:

```
<form action="">
  <input id="user" type="text" required />

  <input id="pass" type="password" placeholder="Password" required />
  <br />
  <button id="btn" type="submit" onclick="validate(event)">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

solution:

```
<form onsubmit="validate(event)">
  <input id="user" type="text" required />

  <input id="pass" type="password" placeholder="Password" required />
  <br />
  <button id="btn" type="submit">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<form action="" method="post">
       <input type = "text" class = "txtPost" placeholder = "Post a   question?" required>
       <button type="submit" class ="btnPost btnBlue">Post</button>
</form>
```

```
    <form action="" method="post">
       <input type = "text" class = "txtPost" placeholder = "Post a   question?" required>
       <button type="submit" class ="btnPost btnBlue">Post</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you missed the form encapsulation:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PhgTM/)

```
<form>
   <input id="tbQuestion" type="text" placeholder="Post a question?" required/>
   <input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

My answer is too late, but it can help others.

I had the same problem, even when I used a form tag.

I solved it by declaring Meta Charset in the header of the page:

```html
<meta charset = "UTF-8" />
```

Answer (score -1):

using form encapsulation and add your button type"submit"

Answer (score -1):

I was facing the same issue. In my case the problem was the return statement within the input tag:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="function_call(); return false;">
```

Removing the `return false;` statement solved my issue.

Answer (score -1):

Check for a novalidate Attribute in the form

novalidate indicates that the form is not to be validated on submit:

```
<form action="/action_page.php" novalidate>
  <label for="email">Enter your email:</label>
  <input type="email" id="email" name="email"><br><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```