# Required attribute doesn't work

Tags: html, forms, required

`required` attribute doesn't work on my form. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code in HTML:

```
<form id="main-contact-form" method="POST">
    <fieldset class="form-group">
      <input id="name" placeholder="Nome" class="form-control" type="text" tabindex="1" required /></fieldset>
    <fieldset class="form-group">
      <input id="email" placeholder="E-mail" class="form-control" type="email" tabindex="2" required /></fieldset>
    <fieldset class="form-group">
      <input id="phone" placeholder="Numero di telefono" class="form-control" type="tel" tabindex="3" required /></fieldset>
    <fieldset class="form-group">
      <textarea id="message" class="form-control" rows="8" placeholder="Scrivi un messaggio.." tabindex="5" required /></textarea></fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <button name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submitBtn">Invia Messaggio</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
<div id="feedback"></div>
```

Here is the php code in the head tag:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $( "#submitBtn" ).click(function( event ) {

        //values
        var name=document.getElementById('name').value;
        var email=document.getElementById('email').value;
        var phone=document.getElementById('phone').value;
        var message=document.getElementById('message').value;
        var dataString = {"name": name, "email":email, "phone": phone, "message":message}

        $.ajax({
            type:"post",
            url:"submitForm.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(html) {
                $('#feedback').html(html);
            }
        });
      event.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I dont know what do you mean by doesn't work ..... it works for me https://jsfiddle.net/uno1ftff/     when I click Invia Messaggio it shows msg

Comment: I don't think there's anything here to prevent the attribute from working, though solely relying on the `required` attribute isn't recommended. Maybe try explicitly setting the attribute as `required="required"` instead of minimizing it.

Comment: [Is your document declared to be HTML 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17966390/html5-required-attribute-seems-not-working#comment26260924_17966390)

Comment: yes, it is      @GSerg

Comment: @Ashish451 the form work, but the required message does not appear, and process the request with empty fields

Comment: I am able to see msg Please fill this field in fiddle which I have attached... In chrome and firefox it shows