# Not able to use the html default required attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using [jquery-tagsinput-revisited](https://github.com/underovsky/jquery-tagsinput-revisited) plugin that displays the data from the database and performs the functionality of autosuggestion and tag. The only issue that I am facing is that it does not go well with HTML default attribute **`required`**.

Ideally, if a required field is empty and we try to submit a form it gives a message telling the user to fill that field, but with this plugin, the required keyword is not displaying the message.

My original i/p field is

```
<input id="value" name="tags-4" type="text"  required>
```

The plugin is replacing this field with its own code and removes the required attribute

I tried to modify the options section by adding the following attribute

```
$('.tagsinput#tags').tagsInput({
  required: required,
  
});
```

but still, I did not get the message.

I want if the field where this plugin used is left empty the user should get a message like this

[image]

> Can anyone please tell me how to do it ?

Comment: You did get a message, just open the console and read it.

Comment: @Teemu yes i get a message in the console saying "form control with name='abc' is not focusable." but i do not know how to use this and display a message as shown in the post

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 required attribute seems not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17966390/html5-required-attribute-seems-not-working)

Comment: @Ismail Farooq It is not a duplicate because the required keyword is individually  working but along with the plugin it is not working