# html how do I make required fields in forms

Tags: html, forms, validation

Is there any way i could make fields required. I tried the using required="required" in the input tag, but it still did not work. is there any other way?

```html
<input name="Forename" type="text" required="required" id="Forename2" onkeyup="allLetter(this)"/>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML5 required attribute seems not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17966390/html5-required-attribute-seems-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The required attribute can simply be included like this:

```
<input required>
```

So in your case, remove the attribute tag:

```
<input name="Forename" type="text" required id="Forename2" onkeyup="allLetter(this)"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can add required to your input field, so it can be :

```
<input name="Forename" type="text" id="Forename2" onkeyup="allLetter(this)" required />
```

Hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to make `required` attribute work you should wrap your inputs into `<form>` tag. After that `onSubmit` event will give you behavior you expected.

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like this:

```js
function validate() {
    var value = document.getElementById("myfield").value;
    //make what you want
    console.log(value);
}
```

```html
<form >
  <label>
  your field: <input type="text" id="myfield" name="my_field" required onkeyup="validate()">
  <input type="submit">
</label>
</form>
```