# Required input with HandleBars

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, template-engine

I'm working with handlebars engine, but my required on input does't work properly, can anyone help me how to use it?

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="nomeLojista">Nome do Lojista:</label>
    <input required type="text" class="form-control id="inputNomeLojista"                                      
     style="max-width: 75%;" placeholder="Entre com o nome do Lojista" >
 </div>
```

this required dont work in my form.

edit: I'm sending my data as json to my end

```
 return fetch('/cadastrarLoja',{
    method: 'POST', 
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "CSRF-Token": Cookies.get("XSRF-TOKEN"),
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ info }),
```

The end point calls my controller to story th data

```
routes.post("/cadastroLoja", LojaController.store);
```

the data is stores in black, the required on hmtl don't work, and the data is send and stored.

Comment: I think you will need to share _what_ is not working about it.

Comment: When i sent a post with a json that contains my form datas to my endpoint, by clicking on my button, the data are saved even if the fields are blank

Comment: Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17966457). You should also move your button into the `<form>` and give it a type of "submit".

Comment: i did that, but when i put an id, and call jquery click function, the required dont work, without the id, works pretty fine